# Best method for auto numbering reports (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, numbers

I'm working on an application that is supposed to be generating calibration certificates. We have like 10 types of certificates.

1. Certificates number should be auto generated.
2. Certificates should be saved in the database (MySQL)
3. numbering should be sequential.

I just want to know the best mechanism for numbering the certificates and persisting the data in the database.

I'm using hibernate by the way.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want an auto incremented field as @bart2puck pointed out.  but, you could also add a custom 'company' and 'certificate' field based upon that number. CONCAT(id,'-',Company,'-',Type) type.  So, a record may look like this

```
ID (auto)     Company      CertificateType    CertificateId

345           22           5601               22-5601-345
```

When you add your index, create it upon (CertificateId,CertificateType,ID)

Comment: I think i will stick to your solution. Thanks

Comment: What do you think if i create a table for each type of certificate that will hold only one record. that record will contain the last issued number so, i will retrieve the record, get the number, increment it and the update the record.

Comment: Sure, I dont see any reason why that would not work.  GL

Comment: Thanks for helping. I will go to continue.

Answer (score 0):

```
 create table certificates (certId bigint(10) auto_increment primary key,//other stuff);
```

Comment: should i count only on the primary key? or is it better if i have a separate table for numbering?

Comment: each cert has its own number or id.  they are unique?  then yes.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. But, there is another question plz. i want the numbering to be based on the company and the certificate type  which makes it more complex. could you help with that? Thanks

Comment: I would *not* use auto-increment for this.

Comment: then no, you can not use auto-increment.  what is an example cert number you want to use?  something like acme10258?   or is it something like all certs from acme start with a 201 and all certs from walmart start with a 301?

Comment: @imorad87 Auto-increment does not guarantee *sequential* numbers; it is also an implementation detail of MySQL and not related to business logic. I recommend having the business logic choose the "correct" report number, whatever it is.

Comment: i have 10 types of certificates (T, TS, B, extra) so i want the number to be like Symbol-Number-year so for example TS01-2014 & B01-2014 a separate numbering for each type depending on how many certificates i will create at run time.

Comment: you would need to use php for this most likely.

Comment: i thought about creating a table for each type of certificate. in every table there will be only one record. i will have to retrieve that record, get the number, increment it and then update the record. What do you think about that?

Comment: I recommend the use of both an autonumbered **primary key** and a natural index,  which may an autoincremented number,  where you can use prefixes and sufixes to categorize the issued certificates.  The autonumbered **PK** must rely on the database,  and the sequential number must rely on a script,  who takes the last issued number and increments,  this, to avoid pitfalls in the autoincrement function of the database, specially of **mysql**

Comment: i thought about creating a coding table for each type of certificate. in every table there will be only one record. i will have to retrieve that record, get the number, increment it and then update the record. What do you think about that?